# How to use event onchange on this case javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How to use event onchange on this case javascript ?

First fill data into input `id="one"` , And then data in input `id="two"` will change data like data in input `id="one"`

But , when data in input `id="two"` change , Why not call `fn_2` function (why not alert) ?

http://jsfiddle.net/A4wxX/111/

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>         
<script>
    function fn_1()
{    
    var aaa = document.getElementById('one').value;            
    document.getElementById("two").value = aaa;
}
</script>


<script>
    function fn_2()
{    
    var bbb = document.getElementById('two').value;    
    alert(bbb);        
}
</script>


<input type="text" id="one" onchange="fn_1()"/>


<input type="text" id="two" onchange="fn_2()" style="display: none"/>
```

Comment: fiddle works fine for me

Comment: @ charlietfl - but when `id="two"` change why not alert ?

Comment: fiddle works fine for me too, you could use 'onblur' instead if somehow in any browser it is not working for you

Comment: @robert dewo I am also seeing alert

Comment: @ Kelsadita - you should to fill data into id="one" only. not alert.

Answer (score 1):

What you wanted is that on change of value of first input box, get this value and set it for second input box and give alert.
In this case onchange event will not get fired. For this you need to manualy call the onchange event of the second input box.

```
<script>
function fn_1() {
    var aaa = document.getElementById('one').value;
    var second_input_elem = document.getElementById("two");
    second_input_elem.value = aaa;
    second_input_elem.onchange();
}
```

Try this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/u09Lurvr/

Answer (score 0):

Its working perfectly.

```
<script>
    function fn_2()
{    
    var bbb = document.getElementById('two').value;    
    document.getElementById("one").value = bbb; 
}
</script>
```

Comment: @ zahangir ahammad - but when id="two" change why not alert ?

Answer (score 0):

`onchange` does work, try clicking outside of the input box once you enter a new value...

But you probably want the value to update instantly...  Using JavaScript's `oninput` you can accomplish this.

```
document.getElementById("one").onchange=function(){ 
    document.getElementById("result_one").innerHTML = this.value;
}

document.getElementById("two").oninput=function(){ 
    document.getElementById("result_two").innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

The element `result_one` updates whenever the status of the element changes.  So `focused` or `blurred`...  While the `result_two` element updates whenever there is new input.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s6bumm8y/) example.

---

**`Edit:`** It appears I misread or misunderstood the question, but it still works regardless.

---

**`Edit 2:`** It seems I misunderstood the question once again...

**Why is there no alert?**

If you're expecting an alert when you put a value into `input one` and the changing value of `input two`, you're looking at it wrong...  The `onchange` function is triggered when the status of an element changes (and for inputs, when the value changes + when the status changes).  The `onchange` function **is not** triggered when the value itself changes...  And for the reason in your example, the alert is not being fired because the status isn't changing, only the value.

But why are you doing this?  You're basically creating two inputs, `input two` just has a value from `input one`...  And you're binding an event on an element where you're creating the value dynamically.  It just seems kinda messy...  A better alternative would be to just fire the alert in `input one`'s function...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fn_1() {    
  var aaa = document.getElementById('one').value;            
  document.getElementById("two").value = aaa;

  var bbb = document.getElementById('two').value;   
  alert(bbb);
}

document.getElementById("one").onchange=fn_1;
</script>

<input type="text" id="one"/>
<input type="text" id="two" style="display: none"/>
```

Comment: @ Xero - but when id="two" change why not alert ?

Comment: @robertdewo, It does work ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A4wxX/109/)) Put something into the box, then click outside of it.  (Remember to click the green check mark if this helped solve your problem)

Comment: still not alert value.

Comment: still not alert , could you please give me some fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

using onchange is useful for select element, in your case it would be better if you use 'onblur':

```
    <script>
function fn_1()
{    
var aaa = document.getElementById('one').value;          
document.getElementById("two").value = aaa;
fn_2();

}

function fn_2()
       {    
var bbb = document.getElementById('two').value;    
alert(bbb);        
}
</script>


<input type="text" id="one" onblur="fn_1()"/>


<input type="text" id="two" onblur="fn_2()" style="display: none"/>
```

Comment: why you use style="display: none", if you want to display the input two after type in input one then you should show it again:

Comment: i use style="display: none"; because i don't want user fill data into id="two"

Comment: if the input two is never shown it can fire the js function, instead not showing put the input two readonly by using: readonly="readonly"

Comment: but if still want input two be hidden call the fn_2() at the end of fn_1() as i edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

`onchange` event will work when some text is changed in the text field and it becomes off focus. 
Hope you want this that way. We are seeing, it is working in that way.

If you want a more automatic way, you can use `onkeyup` for `id="one"` field and `onkeypress` for `id="two"` field but it should be made visible in that case

e.g.

```
//no need to include jQuery library when you are not using it
<script  type="text/javascript">
    function fn_1()
{    
    var aaa = document.getElementById('one').value;            
    document.getElementById("two").value = aaa;
}

    function fn_2()
{    
    var bbb = document.getElementById('two').value;    
    alert(bbb);        
}
</script>


<input type="text" id="one" onkeyup="fn_1()" />

<input type="text" id="two" onkeypress="fn_2()" />
```

Since you have made 2nd field invisible in your example, you will never get an alert as how someone will try onchange event for it? Could you let us know how the data will be handled in 2nd field? Will data be filled into it via some JavaScript event (and thus you want `onchange` event) or directly by putting cursor into it and changing? If so, then it's already working.